# Reduce relocatable win32 Perl to as few files and bytes as possible

Tags: perl, par

I'm trying to use a perl program on a Windows HTCondor computing cluster. The way HTCondor on windows works is it copies all dependencies into a temporary directory (used as a `chroot` of sorts) and then it deletes the directory after the specified outputs are moved to a designated place.

If I take only perl.exe and perl514.dll and make a job like this: `perl -e "print qq/hello\n/"` and tell the cluster to run it 200 times, then each replication winds up taking about 15 seconds, which is acceptable overhead. That's almost all time spent repeatedly copying the files over the network and then deleting them. `echo_hello.bat` run 200 times takes more like two seconds per replication.

The problem I have is that when I try to use my full blown perl distribution of 55MB and 2,289 files, a single "hello" rep takes something like four minutes of copying and deleting, which is unacceptable. When I try to do many runs the disks on the machines grind to a halt trying to concurrently handle all the file operations across all the reps, so it doesn't work at all. I don't know how long it might take to eventually finish because I gave up after half an hour and no jobs had finished.

I figured PAR::Packer might fix the issue, but nope. I tried `print_hello.exe` created like this: `pp -o print_hello.exe -e "print qq/hello\n/"`. It still makes things grind to a halt, apparently by swamping the filesystem. I think a PAR::Packer executable makes a ton of temporary files as it pulls out files it needs from the archive. I think the windows file system totally chokes when there are a bunch of concurrent small file operations.

So how can I go about cutting down the perl I built to something like 6MB and a dozen files? I'm really only using a tiny number of core modules and don't need most of the crap in `bin` and `lib`, but I have no idea how to proceed ripping out stuff in a sane way.

Is there an automated way to strip away un-needed files and modules?

I know TCL has a bunch of facilities for packing files into a single uncompressed archive that can then be accessed through a "virtual filesystem" without expanding the file. Is there some way to do this with perl itself sort of like with PAR? The problem is PAR compresses everything and then has to extract to temporary files, rather than directly work through a virtual filesystem layer. (If I understand correctly.)

My usage of perl is actually as a scripting layer. It's embedded in a simulation. So I'm really running my_simulation.exe which depends on per514.dll, but you get the idea. I also cannot realistically do anything to the HTCondor cluster other than use it. So there's no need to think outside the box on what I should be using instead of perl and what I could administratively tweak in Windows and HTCondor, thanks.

Comment: You can *list* the modules that are needed by your program using the very nice [`ListDependencies` module](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=203148). To my knowledge it isn't downloadable anywhere, but it is simple to copy and paste into your own `ListDependencies.pm` file. You should read the POD documentation within the module for usage instructions

Comment: I'm probably only depending on something like 10 modules (just a guess), but in practice that's probably dozens of files. So I still need some way to condense them down to an archive. It's the small file copies that are killing me. I don't think identifying what can be deleted is a super difficult problem. ListDependencies will probably help some, thanks. The issue, though, is mostly getting the file count down somehow.

Comment: *"10 modules, but in practice that's probably dozens of files"*  Is that based on any real information? I can tell you for certain that there will be *nowhere near* 2,289 files for ten modules. Most modules -- especially Perl-only modules -- consist of only a single file, and there's no need for the POD documentation files for the bigger ones. You haven't given any clue about what dependencies your program is likely to have, so we're in the dark here. If you dismiss every suggestion you get on a whim, and without giving any detail of the application, then you won't get any useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Module::ScanDeps](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::ScanDeps) to get list of actual dependencies of your perl. It was terrible, that it took significant amount of time, when `PAR::Packer` unpacked the whole application, so I decided to build the executable by myself.

[Here](https://github.com/basiliscos/iston/blob/master/static-build/pm-gatherer.pl) is my ready to use script which gathers perl dependencies into some directory; it might be useful for you to reduce the number of perl-modules, e.g. by manually removing some dependencies after copying.

In theory (I have never tried that), the next your step could be merge all pure-perl dependencies into single file (like `deps.pm`); although it might be non-trivial due to perl's autoload magic and some other tricks.

Comment: A mix of scandeps.pl and deleting things to see if everything still works seems to be the best I can do.

Answer (score 1):

You can *list* the modules that are needed by your program using the very nice [`ListDependencies` module](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=203148)

To my knowledge it isn't downloadable anywhere, but it is simple to copy and paste into your own `ListDependencies.pm` file

You should read the POD documentation within the module for usage instructions